# A question on Distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I am self-learning probability theory from Grimmett and Stirzaker's `Probability and random processes`. I am also somewhat new to analysis and learning about sequences and series of real numbers. I have no inkling of the answer to the below question, and I am not sure, if my intuition is correct. Any inputs/help will be awesome!

Exercise 2.3.1 on page 35 asks,

> Let $X$ be a random variable with the distribution function $F$, and let $a = (a_m : -\infty < m < \infty)$ be a strictly increasing sequence of real numbers satisfying $a_{-m} \to -\infty$ and $a_m \to \infty$ as $m \to \infty$. Define $G(x)=P(X\le a_m)$ when $a_{m-1} \le x < a_m$, so that $G$ is the distribution function of a discrete random variable. How does the function $G$ behave as the sequence $a$ is chosen in such a way that $\sup_m \vert {a_m - a_{m-1}} \vert$ becomes smaller and smaller?

**My Intuitive understanding.**

[image]

When $a_{m-1} \le x < a_m$, $G(x) = F(a_m)$. Hence, $G$ is a step function, it is the distribution function of a discrete random variable. If the largest distance between the successive terms of the sequence $a_{m-1}$ and $a_m$ i.e. $\sup \vert a_m - a_{m-1}\vert$ is made smaller and smaller, $G$ goes from being a step-wise function to a smooth curve with no jump discontinuities. Hence, it approaches the distribution function of a continuous random variable.

Answer (score 1):

> $G$ goes from being a step-wise function to a smooth curve with no jump discontinuities. Hence, it approaches the distribution function of a continuous random variable.

Not necessarily: $F$ itself might not be continuous. But I think your intuition is mostly correct. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$
|G(x) - F(x)|
= |\mathbb{P}(X \leq x + \delta) - F(x)|
= |F(x + \delta) - F(x)|
$$

where $0 < \delta \leq \sup_m|a_m - a_{m-1}|$. Since $F$ is a cumulative distribution function, it is right continuous. Therefore, the quantity above converges to $0$ as $\delta \to 0$. Therefore, $G$ converges to $F$ (pointwise) as $\sup_m|a_m - a_{m-1}| \to 0$.

---

Note that the solution above differs from the published solution, so I'd be keen to know if there is a mistake in my logic. The published solution only guarantees convergence at points where $F$ is continuous:

> With $\delta = \sup_m|a_m − a_{m−1}|$, we have that
> $$|F(x) - G(x)| \leq F(a_m) - F(a_{m-1}) \leq |F(x + \delta) - F(x - \delta)|$$
> for $x\in [a_{m-1}, a_m)$. Hence $G(x)$ approaches $F(x)$ for any $x$ at which $F$ is continuous.